Cannot add a Root Component <GUID> of type 29 because it is not in the target system
I am trying to create a workflow in my Customer Dynamics 365 (Customer Service) environment.
I am trying to create it within a solution from scratch - so the workflow with this guid does not exist in the environment (I want it to appear once I import the solution). I have it defined in customizations.xml and in solution.xml as shown in the code snippets below.
I tried referring to it by the schemaName in solution.xml with no luck (in analogy with WebResource - that one I was able to create and refer within the solution). The referred xaml contains definition of a workflow that I created previously via portal, exported and removed from the environment, so it should be correct (solution was also importing correctly whilst the workflow with that id existed in the environment). I am using API version 9.1.
I am getting the "Cannot add a Root Component c73e3d27-f75e-ef11-bfe3-000d3ad4b474 of type 29 because it is not in the target system." and I am out of ideas now... Any help?..
solution.xml:
...
<RootComponents>
      <RootComponent type="1" schemaName="incident" behavior="1" />
      <RootComponent type="61" schemaName="py15_caseTypeFilterLib" behavior="0" />
      <RootComponent type="29" id="{c73e3d27-f75e-ef11-bfe3-000d3ad4b474}" behavior="2" />
      <!--RootComponent type="29" schemaName="py15_caseTypeWorkflow" behavior="2" /-->
</RootComponents>
<MissingDependencies />

customizations.xml:
...
<Workflows>
        <Workflow WorkflowId="{c73e3d27-f75e-ef11-bfe3-000d3ad4b474}" Name="py15_caseTypeWorkflow">
            <XamlFileName>/Workflows/ReplaceCaseType.xaml</XamlFileName>
            <Name>py15_caseTypeWorkflow</Name>
            <Type>1</Type>
            <Subprocess>0</Subprocess>
            <Category>0</Category>
            <Mode>0</Mode>
            <Scope>4</Scope>
            <OnDemand>0</OnDemand>
            <TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList>casetypecode</TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList>
            <TriggerOnCreate>1</TriggerOnCreate>
            <TriggerOnDelete>0</TriggerOnDelete>
            <AsyncAutodelete>1</AsyncAutodelete>
            <SyncWorkflowLogOnFailure>0</SyncWorkflowLogOnFailure>
            <StateCode>1</StateCode>
            <StatusCode>2</StatusCode>
            <RunAs>1</RunAs>
            <IsTransacted>1</IsTransacted>
            <IntroducedVersion>1.0.0.0</IntroducedVersion>
            <IsCustomizable>1</IsCustomizable>
            <BusinessProcessType>0</BusinessProcessType>
            <IsCustomProcessingStepAllowedForOtherPublishers>1</IsCustomProcessingStepAllowedForOtherPublishers>
            <PrimaryEntity>Incident</PrimaryEntity>
            <LocalizedNames>
                <LocalizedName languagecode="1033" description="Replace Case Type"/>
            </LocalizedNames>
        </Workflow>
    </Workflows>
</ImportExportXml>


Why not create the workflow in UI and then include it in your solution?

@ray gan That's where I started. It worked, then I deleted the workflow from the environment to mimic transferring it into a new env and now it's giving me the error described in the post.
